# Pandas Sum Specific Rows of Dataframe Provided By Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with a column of keys, and some other columns. I want to merge together (sum) specific rows of the dataframe. Which rows should be summed together is provided by a dictionary. This mapping is provided by a dictionary of of { key : [ list of other keys ] }.

Concretely, here is some sample code:

```
data = [('A', 4, 10),
        ('B', 7, 10),
        ('C', 3, 9)]
labels = ['Key','Col1','Col2']
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=labels)

idx_grouping_dict = { 'A' : ['C'], 'B' : ['A'], 'C' : ['A', 'B']}


desired_result = pd.DataFrame(
        [('A', 7, 19),
         ('B', 11, 20),
         ('C', 14, 29)], columns=labels)
```

Here, the row with index 'A' gets added to the row with index 'C', the row with index 'B' gets added to the row with index 'A', and the row with index 'C' gets added to both rows 'A' and 'B'.

I'm sure there's a way to do this! Perhaps forming some sort of temporary dataframe and using a clever inner or outer join? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a data frame from the dictionary with key and value as two separate columns, join it with `mydf` and then group by the key column(from the original dictionary) and sum columns up:

```
pd.DataFrame([(g, k) for g, ks in idx_grouping_dict.items() for k in ks + [g]], 
             columns=["GKey", "Key"]).merge(mydf).groupby("GKey", as_index=False).sum()

#GKey   Col1    Col2
#0  A      7      19
#1  B     11      20
#2  C     14      29
```

---

```
keydf = pd.DataFrame([(g, k) for g, ks in idx_grouping_dict.items() for k in ks + [g]], columns=["GKey", "Key"])

keydf
#GKey   Key
#0  C     A
#1  C     B
#2  C     C
#3  B     A
#4  B     B
#5  A     C
#6  A     A

keydf.merge(mydf)

#GKey Key Col1 Col2
#0  C   A    4   10
#1  B   A    4   10
#2  A   A    4   10
#3  C   B    7   10
#4  B   B    7   10
#5  C   C    3    9
#6  A   C    3    9

keydf.merge(mydf).groupby('GKey', as_index=False).sum()

#GKey   Col1    Col2
#0  A      7      19
#1  B     11      20
#2  C     14      29
```

---

Another option:

```
val_df = mydf.set_index("Key")
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({g: val_df.loc[[g] + ks].sum() for g, ks in idx_grouping_dict.items()}, orient="index")

# Col1  Col2
#A   7    19
#B  11    20
#C  14    29
```

*Timing*:

```
%%timeit
val_df = mydf.set_index("Key")
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({g: val_df.loc[[g] + ks].sum() for g, ks in idx_grouping_dict.items()}, orient="index")
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.51 ms per loop

%timeit pd.DataFrame([(g, k) for g, ks in idx_grouping_dict.items() for k in ks + [g]], columns=["GKey", "Key"]).merge(mydf).groupby("GKey", as_index=False).sum()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.22 ms per loop
```

Comment: Awesome answer plus 1

Comment: @Bharathshetty Thank you.

Comment: This is clever !

Comment: @MaxU Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MaxU Your solution to my question helped with my answer :) This is still faster.

Answer (score 3):

This is a (slightly) slower solution, which involves transposing the dataframe first and then a performing column wise sum before transposing it back.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332338/4909087
In [457]: temp = mydf.T.rename_axis(None, axis=1)

In [456]: pd.DataFrame({k : temp[[k]].join(temp[[i for i in v]]).agg('sum', axis=1) for k, v in idx_grouping_dict.items()}).T
Out[456]: 
   Col1  Col2
A     7    19
B    11    20
C    14    29
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution base on `Dataframe` ..

```
idx_grouping_dict = { 'A' : ['C'], 'B' : ['A'], 'C' : ['A', 'B']}
s = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(idx_grouping_dict, name='Va'))
s.apply(lambda x: x['Va'].append(x.name), axis=1)
Temp_unnest = pd.DataFrame([[i, x]
              for i, y in s['Va'].apply(list).iteritems()
                  for x in y], columns=list('IV'))
data = [('A', 4, 10),
        ('B', 7, 10),
        ('C', 3, 9)]
labels = ['Key','Col1','Col2']
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=labels)
Temp_unnest=Temp_unnest.merge(mydf,left_on='V',right_on='Key',how='left')
Temp_unnest.groupby('I').sum()


   Col1  Col2
I            
A     7    19
B    11    20
C    14    29
```