# How do I transpose a pandas dataframe in a certain fashion?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df` like this:

```
     Col1  Col2
Key            
A       4    10
B       7    10
C       3     9
```

My desired data frame is

```
            A   B  C                   
    Col1    4   7  3
    Col2   10  10  9
```

Where `Col1` and `Col2` are the indices.

How would I specify this? I've tried:

```
In [419]: mydf.T.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[419]: 
Key   A   B  C
0     4   7  3
1    10  10  9
```

But for some reason, the `Key` remains. I'm not sure what it is, and I'm not sure how to get rid of it. I've also tried `mydf.T.reset_index().set_index('index')` but it is very unsightly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we can use [DataFrame.rename_axis()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) here:

```
In [24]: df.T.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
Out[24]:
       A   B  C
Col1   4   7  3
Col2  10  10  9
```

Comment: Great answer! +1

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i strongly believe that one of the best way to learn something is to start answering questions on SO. So we are on the right track ;-)